# Append to delimited text file

Tags: vba, excel

`I want to use a macro in vba that:

1. Takes values of the selected cells in given excel sheet. Asks for selection if there are no selected cells.
2. Checks if a certain text file (comma delimited) exists.
3. Appends values if the file exists, creates file and adds values if the file does not exist (comma delimited).

Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub Wri()

Dim myrng As Range

Set myrng = Range("A1:A22222")

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0
Dim fs, f, ts, s
Dim cellv As String

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fs.CreateTextFile "C:\Users\HP\Documents\fil.txt"
Set f = fs.GetFile("C:\Users\HP\Documents\fil.txt")
Set ts = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, TristateFalse)

For Each cell In myrng
    cellv = cell.Value
    ts.Write (cellv & Chr(44))
Next cell
End Sub
```

`
I want to use a range the user selects and append

Comment: Add here the code you have tried and the problems you encountered.

Comment: what problems do you have with current your code?

Comment: I want to take a user selected range not a specified range.

Comment: Also, I want to know how to append instead of write. ForAppending did not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub MainProc()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Select range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No cells selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
        WriteToFile Cell, "Hello World!"
    Next Cell
End Sub

Private Sub WriteToFile(Rng As Range, s As String)
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim TS As TextStream

    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject

    Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(Rng.Value, ForAppending, True, TristateFalse)
    TS.WriteLine s
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting an error, saying User defined type not defined at: Private Sub WriteToFile(Rng As Range, s As String)

Comment: I used early binding via reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime. You need to use late binding if you don't have this reference in your project. `Dim FSO As Object`, `Dim TS As Object`, `Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`, `Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(Rng.Value, 3, True, 0)`

Comment: Private Sub WriteToFile(Rng As Range, s As String)

    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
    Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0
    
    Dim FSO As Object
    
    Dim TS As Object
    

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    

    Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(Rng.Value, 3, True, 0)   'The error is here now'
    TS.WriteLine s
    
End Sub

Comment: You misled me with your values of constants. `ForAppending` is equal to `8`. So it should be Set `TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(Rng.Value, 8, True, 0)`

Comment: Thanks, the code is running smooth now, but its giving me undefined files for each cell value, not one comma delimited text file.